# Lambda function created by Serverless framework includes other folders from root

Tags: serverless-framework

Is there a way I can exclude the readme file and sls-templates (which contains my other serverless code) folder from getting uploaded to lambda? I deployed using the serverless framework and it is kind of weird to see my other serverless templates files showing up. Not a big deal though I'm just worried about the size in case my Serverless code base expands.

[image]

Comment: Could you post your serverless.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. You can manually include or exclude files in your `serverless.yml`.

```
package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
```

See more here:
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/

Comment: thanks. I got the path wrong when excluding. I read the documentation (and this is just on the side) do you know what this does?
`package:
  individually: true
`

Comment: Individual packaging allows you to specify an include and exclude list for each function. You can read more here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/

Answer (score 0):

For those whom above explanations might not be matching, this source also outlines it well   https://filip5114.github.io/sls-manage-function-package/